# Hide a specific word from displaying when working with an array

Tags: php

I am currently working on a property website and when retrieving stats from an array i do not want to show one in particular called 'post_title'. Here is the code

```
<?php if ( have_properties() ) { ?>



<ul class="<?php wpp_css('property_featured_shortcode::featured_properties',   "wpp_featured_properties_shortcode clearfix"); ?>">

<?php foreach ( returned_properties('load_gallery=false') as $property) {  ?>

<li class="<?php wpp_css('property_featured_shortcode::property', "{$class} wpp_featured_property_container wp-caption clearfix"); ?>" >



  <a class="<?php wpp_css('property_featured_shortcode::thumbnail', "featured_property_thumbnail"); ?>"  href="<?php echo $property['permalink']; ?>">

    <?php property_overview_image($thumbnail_size); ?>

  </a>



  <?php if(is_array($stats)): ?>

    <ul class="<?php wpp_css('property_featured_shortcode::stats', "wp-caption-text shortcode_featured_properties"); ?>">



      <?php foreach($stats as $stat):

        if(empty($property[$stat])) continue;

        ?>

        <li class="<?php echo $stat; ?>">

          <dl>

            <dt><?php echo (empty($wp_properties['property_stats'][$stat]) ? ucwords($stat) : $wp_properties['property_stats'][$stat]); ?>:</dt>

            <dd><?php echo $property[$stat];  ?></dd>

          </dl>

        </li>

      <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>

  <?php endif; ?>



</li>

<?php } ?>

</ul>



<?php } ?>
```

and this is the result

[image: the result].

How can i go about hiding the post title please?.

I have tried changing it to echo just title by trying the code below but it did not work.

```
<?php if ([$stat] == 'post_title') echo 'Title' ?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: to clarify, its just the word 'post_title' i would like to hide not the actual property title (address). Thanks

Comment: pls post print_r of $stats array

Comment: I can't even find the string `post_title` inside that chaotic code...

Comment: also show print_r of $wp_properties['property_stats'] array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you need to change is the label, which is being output by this code (you can tell from the colon being output at the end):

```
<?php echo (empty($wp_properties['property_stats'][$stat]) ? ucwords($stat) : $wp_properties['property_stats'][$stat]); ?>:
```

Try this:

```
<?php echo (empty($wp_properties['property_stats'][$stat]) ? ucwords($stat == 'post_title'? 'Title': $stat) : $wp_properties['property_stats'][$stat]); ?>:
```

Comment: Asad, you are a life saver, It works like a charm. I can't thank you enough. Spent all day working on that. My gratitude goes out to you :D. Thanks again.